# Cannot connect to aurora, checked security group & publicly accesible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I have an Aurora cluster with 2 instances, 1 writer 1 reader.
I was connected just fine migrating data and then all of a sudden, connection gets dropped.
After that, I cannot connect to it.
I've checked the security group, it has my ip, and I even allowed inbound from any just testing.
The status of both is "available" so its not a storage-full thing (plus I haven't even uploaded more than a GB).

I've double-triple-multi checked the security group, it's the one assigned and the inbound rules.
The instances are in available status.
I can't even get a response from the server, it's not about bad credentials.

```
nc -zv rowcapital1-cluster.cluster-c7tbknvcs8aj.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com 3306
rowcapital1-cluster.cluster-c7tbknvcs8aj.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com [34.227.210.213] 3306 (mysql): Operation timed out



mysql -h rowcapital1-cluster.cluster-c7tbknvcs8aj.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -P 3306
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'rowcapital1-cluster.cluster-c7tbknvcs8aj.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws' (36)
```

I'm at loss... This is driving me crazy... Does someone have any insight?
I'm about to take a flight in less than a day and I need this up.

And I cannot post this on AWS forum because the account is "too recent"...
And tech support is payed...

Amazon what are you doing??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Restarting the server didn't work.
I changed the publicly available option to no, applied immediately.
Waited.
Changed back publicly available to yes, applied immediately again.

Access is back.